# How to execute VBScript command within textbox from C# application?

Tags: c#, vbscript, textbox

How could I execute VBScript's code from TextBox control placed in C# application?

like , let's assume that I have a C# Windows Application(form)
and has two controls!

1. textbox (txtCode)
2. button (btnExecute)

txtCode has VBScript code
and I want when clicking at btnExecute to execute the VBScript code!!

Comment: can't you get the value written in the txtCode texbox and on the btnExecute click method execute it?

Comment: @Muhamad: Why do you wanna harass C# application ??

Comment: @EmreVeriyaz and how do you plan to do that.. VBScript is a Client side scripting language .. so it will only run in a browser with Either a `html` page or an `Hyper Text Application`.

Comment: @Shekhar it is good to learn, thanks.

Comment: @Shekhar [Windows Script Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k(v=VS.85).aspx) does not need `html` or `hta`

Comment: @oracle certified professional : thanx.. i didn't knew that

Answer (score 3):

You can pass VBS/JS directly to the scripting runtime & pass code & objects around.

Add a ref to the Microsoft Scripting Control (COM) then you can;

```
MSScriptControl.ScriptControl sc = new MSScriptControl.ScriptControl();
object[] anyParams = { "Bob"};
string expr = @"function foo(arg)
    dim x: x = ""Hello "" & arg 
    msgbox x
    foo = 12345 
    End function";

sc.Language = "VBScript";
sc.AddCode(expr);

object result = sc.Run("foo", ref anyParams);

//also
sc.Reset();
result = sc.Eval("1 + 2 / 3 + abs(-99)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [**`WebBrowser`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) Control to do that.

And since i don't think you can inject VBScript code in the loaded page. So what you can do is Create a Temp `.html` page, save your TextBox's script in it and then Load it in the the WebBrowser Control.

Comment: VBScript is not just a browser scripting language, it can be used with [Windows Script Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k(v=VS.85).aspx), as well as server-side ASP

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you simply write it to a file and execute it using the default Windows behavior or something like that? It's the only way I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this two articles:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc301954.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974577.aspx